# Colorize grayscale image using graphicsmagick

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm having trouble colorizing (not sure if that's the correct term) a grayscale image using graphicsmagick.

Here is my starting image.

[image: Image1]

This is what I would like the result to be like. It doesn't necessarily have to be green, but I would like to be able to specify an RGB value if possible.

[image: Image2]

My result currently looks like this, don't laugh...

[image]

I'm currently performing multiple manipulations to the image, but colorizing it is the last step.

This is a portion of my code performing this action, irrelevant stuff has been taken out.

```
  gm('/tmp/'+uid+'.jpg').size(function(err, size) {
    /* croping and resizing is taking place here */
    this.write('/tmp/'+uid+'.jpg', function(err) {
      this.colorize(200, 200, 256);
      this.write("photos/processed/"+filename.replace(".jpg", ".png"), function(err) {
        if (err) console.log("error");
        else console.log("success");
        fs.unlink('/tmp/image'+uid+'.jpg');
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't speak *node*, but try fully desaturating the image first then applying your `colorize()` and change the `256` to `255` by the way.